# Asus Windows 8 Computer black screen and cursor

Tags: windows-8, virus, black-screen-of-death, blank-screen, asus-laptop

Yesterday my friend sent me a link and I clicked on the link. The computer gave me a warning about it being harmful but since it always does that I allowed it to open the link anyway. The link was immediately detected by my antivirus and quarantined. I logged off the computer but now everytime I try to use my account there is only a black screen and a cursor nothing else. It stays there for hours. But if I use another users account, everything works properly. Please help, there are several documents that I need to access in my account as its the only admin account on the laptop.

Comment: Can you access the file on the admin account from the other account. Check `C:\Users` to find out.

Comment: Yes I can. I can access all documents on my account from the guest account, but I really want to be able to use my account too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Run an effective antivirus boot-time scan, which should remove any malware. You do not state what antivirus you're using, but if it doesn't fix the issue, try another, such as Kaspersky free scan: http://free.kaspersky.com/, Malwarebytes Free: http://www.malwarebytes.org/lp/malware_lp_form/, or Avast! Free: https://www.avast.com/en-us/index.

Do not install **two** real-time antiviruses as they will conflict with each other, but Malwarebytes and Kaspersky can be set to run only upon request.

Though you can install and run the AV software from the other account(s), to be most effective, you might need to make a bootable USB device with an antimalware applications. See http://pcsupport.about.com/od/system-security/tp/free-bootable-antivirus-software.htm for a list. The virus definitions become outdated, so use a newly-made tool.

Comment: Thank you. Usually I use AVG antivirus but I downloaded CCleaner and clean several things on the computer, I also used malwarebytes but still have that blank screen when I log into my account.